# Reactjs : Read value of a Radio Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

I have the following code for radio selection control:

```
    <Radio
        inline
        id={item}
        enter code herename="stackedRadios"
        value={item}
        label={item}
        checked={this.state.checked == item}
        onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, item, quesId)}
    />
```

The handle change function is :

```
    handleChange (value, quesId) {
        this.setState({checked: value})
    }
```

In the handle change function what I am trying to print the value on console but nothing is printed on console.
Now what I want is to get the selected value from the radio but failing to get so. Please help with the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've used bind with 2 args, `event` which is normally the first arg, will be the third.

```
 handleChange (value, quesId, event) {
   this.setState({ checked: event.target.checked })
 }
```

If you don't need the first two values then don't bind. Also you shouldn't use bind inside of render as this causes the Radio component to have new props every render even if nothing changed, since a new function is created every render.

Comment: Btw: A discussion about performance issues of inline functions by Ryan Florance (author of redux-router): https://cdb.reacttraining.com/react-inline-functions-and-performance-bdff784f5578